# Bootstrap Button Group, how to handle

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple webpage in Ruby on Rails and want users to be able to pay for credit through a simple pre-set PayPal button. So I have the following button group:

```
    <form>
     <div class="btn-group"> 
    <div class="input-append" align="center">
      <input class="span4" required id="appendedInputButtons" type="text" name="fUsername" placeholder="username">
      <button class="btn" type="button">€ 1</button>
      <button class="btn" type="button">€ 5</button>
      <button class="btn" type="button">€ 10</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

looks like:

[image: button-group bootstrap]

My plan is (maybe there is a better way) is to post the username together with the amount to a php file, which will send an email with the username and desired amount to my inbox. The user is redirected to a PayPal button and they can pay there. I manually check if a user paid and handle the order.
I couldn't find a way to have PayPal handle the order after a successful payment, since I have to pass the username.

I know how to deal with 1 button in a form:

```
   <form action="action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But how to deal with 3 buttons in a group?

Comment: please could you make it clear. I didn't understand anything of what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: Give each one a name attribute and catch the one that is clicked by looking for isset($_POST['whicheverbutton'])? They are only grouped visually, they are still just three buttons.

Comment: @Newben I have a server that accepts for example http://post.php?username=UN&amount=5, but I want to accept payments first and the cheapest and easiest way (for Europe) seems PayPal, but I don't think I can pass the username.

Comment: @mjayt, so I should make all three of the type submit and that sets the button, so I should add name=button1?

Comment: I am still not sure of what you are doing. But two possibilities. Ether you can pass multiple parameters to `paypal` which I think it is possible (since I already experienced it), another way is to store some data you can't pass to `paypal` in a session, and then unset the session after successfull callback

Comment: @mjayt I think diego is using ror and not php in his app;) `action.php` is the `paypal` url (I guess)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using RoR, but was planning on having a php file to send me a mail and then link the user to a paypal button, but I'm going to look into the session or CUSTOM field in PayPal

Comment: @newben good point... missed that. I think the front end portion still applies though. Diego, yes, I would change them to submit buttons and give them a value matching the amount.

Comment: Great, I'm going to work on this, you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: How about having an <input type='hidden'> tag and update its value using jQuery on every click of the button.. Then the amount will be automatically passed using the form action